# Change the number of gridlines appearing in the plotting of pandas dataframe through matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
 Close       1dv       2dv        3dv        4dv
Date                                                            
2022-05-20  109.313004       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
2022-05-23  111.666496  2.353492       NaN        NaN        NaN
2022-05-24  105.926003 -5.740493 -8.093985        NaN        NaN
2022-05-25  105.839500 -0.086503  5.653990  13.747975        NaN
2022-05-26  108.295998  2.456498  2.543001  -3.110989 -16.858964
2022-05-27  112.799004  4.503006  2.046508  -0.496493   2.614496
2022-05-31  114.039001  1.239997 -3.263009  -5.309517  -4.813024
2022-06-01  114.137001  0.098000 -1.141997   2.121012   7.430529
2022-06-02  117.746002  3.609001  3.511001   4.652998   2.531986
```

Which I plotted through the following code:

```
plt.figure()
d1m.plot(linewidth=0.5)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

No matter what I do, I'am not able to get vertical lines corresponding to each index label on the y-axis. I even tried

```
plt.grid(True)
```

or

```
plt.grid(markevery=3)
```

etc.
I'am still getting the same image where only some dates in the y-axis have vertical lines in the grids, where-as I want to have vertical lines at every y-axis label. Here, date is not only the index, but also the y-axis.

What do I do?

Comment: it works as expected on my system. All index has a vertical line.

Comment: @QuangHoang its not working on my pc. Any solutions? I want all indexes to have vertical grid lines.